# How many slaps to cook human?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, estimation, thermal-conductivity

Since when we slap something, some of the kinetic energy turns into thermal energy, is it possible to slap a human so quick and hard, that it gets cooked? And how many slaps at the least possible time be needed to cook a human ?

Comment: here is the same question answered https://www.quora.com/If-kinetic-energy-is-converted-into-thermal-energy-how-hard-do-I-have-to-slap-a-chicken-to-cook-it

Comment: hopefully, any cannibals out there could profit from this.

Comment: Noob, I was seeing how to cook my friends by slapping them as a joke.

Comment: This is one of those great questions where the answer doesn't matter but *how* you approach the problem matters a lot.  So, make some estimates as to the amount of energy transferred per slap, compare with, e.g.,  the amount of energy used to raise the body to 145 F (internally) as you would a roast beef in the oven.  Add in a term for radiated energy if you like